# Filtrar objeto con datos en formato fecha

Tags: javascript, array, web, objeto

Tengo el siguiente objeto y quiero agruparlos por fechas y poder ingresar a la cantidad completa de esas fechas. Por ejemplo:

Quiero guardar la cantidad de enero del objeto por el U_Subrubro:'00000189'

Pero no se como hacerlo. Intenté con reduce pero no logro hacerlo. Me gustaría guardar en otro objeto la cantidad al mes correspondiente, Enero, Febrero etc. Cambien estoy usando MomentJS pero no logro hacerlo. Si alguien puede me explica como lo hizo me ayudaría bastante gracias

```
[
{
    "DocDate": "2022-01-19",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 1
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-30",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 6
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-01-03",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 5
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-10-27",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 3
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-19",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 1
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-09",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 4
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-10-19",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 3
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-18",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 4
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-01-22",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 2
},
{
    "DocDate": "2022-01-08",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 2
},
   
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-15",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 3
},
{
    "DocDate": "2021-11-01",
    "BPLName": "003",
    "U_Subrubros": "00000189",
    "Cantidad": 2
},
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que `docs` es el array de ejemplo que compartiste, prueba usar esta función.

```
const reducedDocs = docs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { DocDate, U_Subrubros, Cantidad } = curr;
    const [year, month] = DocDate.split('-');

    if (!acc[U_Subrubros]) acc[U_Subrubros] = {};
    if (!acc[U_Subrubros][year]) acc[U_Subrubros][year] = {};
    if (!acc[U_Subrubros][year][month]) acc[U_Subrubros][year][month] = 0;

    acc[U_Subrubros][year][month] += Cantidad;

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reducedDocs);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me sirvió. Pero ahora necesito acceder al valor de las keys del objeto. Por que esto me devuelve {
  00000189:
2021:
01: 76
02: 54
03: 65
04: 82
05: 27
06: 23
07: 49
08: 54
09: 41
10: 58
11: 59
12: 58

Como puedo acceder directamente al valor de cada key? Por ejemplo del 01 02 acceder al valor que serian 76 54 etc

Comment: `const value = reducedDocs['00000189']['2021']['01'];`